# "The requested URL /projectname/pagename/ was not found on this server." issue on WordPress website

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

For my WordPress project, I am getting the error `The requested URL /projectname/pagename/ was not found on this server.` when I try to set the permalink to `Postname: http://10.60.8.118/projectname/sample-post/`. The project is hosted on my Ubuntu machine.

[image]

I am able to view the pages or posts with permalinks set as `Plain: http://10.60.8.118/projectname/?p=123`

Earlier .htaccess was not writable. So I changed it and now it is writable.

**content of .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /devcounsyl/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The above settings does not work. I have also tried changing the base to / (I guess it should be /devcounsyl/ but none of them works.)

**content of .htaccess**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Also tried:** Changing file and folder permissions assuming that that might be causing the issue:

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \;

find . -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

**database urls:**

`wp_options` table has the value `http://10.60.8.118/devcounsyl` for `siteurl` and `home`

Project structure:

`/var/www/html/devcounsyl/`

The WordPress files are in the project folder and also the `.htaccess` file is in `devcounsyl` project folder.

Comment: check url from your database in options table

Comment: Hi Pankaj. `wp_options` table has the value `http://10.60.8.118/devcounsyl` for `siteurl` and `home`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that `.htaccess` was not the issue for me. The issue was in server configuration file. Posting my answer in case any one bumps into similar issue and looking for a solution.

**For AWS EC2 server:**

**Step 1: Edit configuration file**

`sudo nano /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Edit this file and change

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Note that here, `/var/www/html/wordpress/` is path to the root folder where WordPress project was hosted.

**Step 2: Restart server**

Please don't forget to restart your server after you do the changes to the `.conf` file.

`sudo service httpd restart`

**For Ubuntu server:**

**Step 1: Edit configuration file**

`sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

Edit this file and change

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride None
 </Directory>
```

to

```
<Directory /var/www/html/wordpress/>
    AllowOverride All
 </Directory>
```

Note that here, `/var/www/html/wordpress/` is path to the root folder where WordPress project was hosted.

**Step 2: Restart server**

Please don't forget to restart your server after you do the changes to the `.conf` file.

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 1):

If WordPress is installed in a subdirectory then you should move your `.htaccess` into that subdirectory (if not already) and remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` *substitution*, otherwise the `RewriteBase` directive will have no effect. For example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase is not required if .htaccess file is in the /devcounsyl dir
#RewriteBase /devcounsyl/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Although, if the `.htaccess` file is already in the `/devconsyl` subdirectory, then the `RewriteBase` directive is not actually required (providing you remove the slash prefix from the `RewriteRule` *substitution*, as mentioned above).

The `.htaccess` file would need to be in the WordPress subdirectory for the first `RewriteRule` to match. (ie. `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`)

By removing the slash prefix, you are making the *substitution* relative to the directory containing the `.htaccess` file. The `RewriteBase` only applies to relative substitutions and simply overrides the default (relative) path.

---

If, however, the `.htaccess` file is located in the document root of your domain (ie. not the WordPress root) then you would need to modify your `.htaccess` like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase is required if .htaccess file is in document root
RewriteBase /devcounsyl/
RewriteRule ^devcounsyl/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Now I understand this better. But for me still it is not working. My project path is `/var/www/html/devcounsyl/` which has .htaccess in it and this is the VM setup so I am connecting through url `http://10.60.8.118/devcounsyl/`. So `devcounsyl` works as root. 
So I have gone with the first option I have shown in my question. 

Is there any chance that `http://10.60.8.118/devcounsyl` the url is causing any issue? Because if I move the files to my local `http://localhost/devcounsyl` works just fine.